# Last observation carried forward (LOCF) for all NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, locf

I would like to have all NA values replaced by the Last Observation Carried Forward (LOCF) method in R. 
The data set I have is below:

```
Value1        Value2           Value3          Group
100           56               82              Group1
150           NA               97              Group2
NA            66               NA              Group3
120           NA               NA              Group4
```

I would like to create the following data set:

```
Value1        Value2           Value3          Group
100           56               82              Group1
150           56               97              Group2
150           66               97              Group3
120           66               97              Group4
```

Any insight on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `fill` from `tidyr`.

```
tidyr::fill(df, everything())

#  Value1 Value2 Value3  Group
#1    100     56     82 Group1
#2    150     56     97 Group2
#3    150     66     97 Group3
#4    120     66     97 Group4
```

Or with `zoo::na.locf`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, zoo::na.locf)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Value1 = c(100L, 150L, NA, 120L), Value2 = c(56L, 
NA, 66L, NA), Value3 = c(82L, 97L, NA, NA), Group = structure(1:4, 
.Label = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foo = function(x) {
    x[cummax((!is.na(x)) * seq_along(x))]
}

data.frame(lapply(df, foo))
```

If the first element can also be `NA`, use the following function

```
foo = function(x) {
    x[cummax(pmax(1, (!is.na(x)) * seq_along(x)))]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a very short solution:

```
library("imputeTS")
na_locf(yourdataframe)
```

That is all you need. Also works the same way for all other time series imputation algorithms provided by the package. The package insists on numeric columns though, non-numeric input columns will be left unchanged.